# Cinemachine lock on

Tags: unity, c#, camera, cinemachine

I'm using Cinemachine for a free look 3rd person camera and a virtual camera for a lock on cam.

I already have switched Cinemachine brains and movement types done, but I need the player to face the target and to keep the player on screen. The player is set as the "follow" with the target as the "look at"

```
public void LockOnMovement()
{
    float nx = movementinput.x;
    float ny = movementinput.y;

    move3 = new Vector3(nx, 0, ny);
    Vector3 rotateMovement = Quaternion.Euler(Cam.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x, 0, 0).normalized * move3;
    controller.Move(rotateMovement * runspeed * Time.deltaTime);
    
}
```

That's the players movement when locked on.

`cam` is the camera the Cinemachine brains are controlling.

Comment: How does the behaviour with your current setup and code differ from what you want?

Comment: well i need the player to stay on screen if u move in a certain the player will be off screen

Comment: also im trying to make the lock on system like the one twilight princess if that helps

Comment: It could help, if you edit your question to document the behaviour of Twilight Princess's  lock on system and how yours currently differs from it.